# minimal bash like line error after removing all linux-images

Tags: grub

I has been using elementary os loki on ubuntu 16 until i removed all linux-image files to install software updates. Suddenly software update center pop up the message to whether i would like to restart to apply the update. i pressed restart now button and then "minimal bash like line editing is supported" screen, that i have never was displayed.

i tried following several advices on this issue using live usb, however,

1. boot-repair doesn't help(it created a link though: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8MhT8frMV4/)
2. chroot after mount doesn't work

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt 
   mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
   ```

fdisk -l result is

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 488396799 487395330 232.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 488396799 487395328 232.4G 83 Linux
```

can i get some advice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You've uninstalled your Linux kernels! :^(** The "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported" message is the bootloader's (GRUB) prompt--think of it as its way of telling you, "I can't boot your computer, and there's not much else for me to do, now what?"

Please refer to questions such as [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/q/28099/549800), which will involve something like using a LiveCD to get back into your installation using a chroot and reinstalling the linux-image packages.

Under normal operation it should not be necessary to remove *all* linux-image packages, even though it does help save significant space to remove older ones.